# Bootstrap Grails from file

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Hey guys I'm new to Grails and I'm getting to the point where I'm learning about the BootStrap.groovy file.  I see that you can create each model and save them one at a time into the database, but is there anyway to load them from a YAML file or something similar.  I'm coming from the Play framework which supports something like that.  I already have a YAML file  with about 80 objects to seed the database with and I really don't want to re write that into new MyObject({blah:blah, blah:blah}).save() for all of them.  Is there anything out there that will handle this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discovered the Groovy Library for [JYaml](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Yaml+and+Groovy), which allows you to instantiate classes from YAML files.  Here is the example they give:

```
@Grab('org.jyaml:jyaml:1.3')
import org.ho.yaml.*

class Staff {
    def firstname, lastname, position
}

input = '''
firstname: John
lastname: Connor
position: Resistance Leader
'''
Staff s = Yaml.loadType(input, Staff)
println s.dump()
// => <Staff@c05d3b firstname=John lastname=Connor position=Resistance Leader>
```

**----EDIT----**

As stated in the comments, `JYAML` is no longer being supported and `SnakeYAML` is the way to go for parsing YAML files.  See the [SnakeYAML examples here](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Loading_YAML).

Comment: You can also use [SnakeYAML](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/) as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1863814/2051952). [JYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/) claims it is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro I'll use SnakeYAML instead.  Please post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I am good, you did the homework. :) It will be great if you can post your version of implementation (or an example as you did for JYaml) using SnakeYaml as an update to the above answer. And accept your own answer. ;)